# Apples will not fall randomly

Tags: javascript, arrays

its my first question here and it would be nice it you point any mistakes here, thanks.

I'm trying to make a game using jQuery. The idea is simple, on a screen you can see 5 apple spawn randomly and one after another they start falling down, so they player have to catch them.

The bug is that all the apples fall at once, even though I use random selection and `setInterval()` to try to make apples fall one at a time.

Obviously something is wrong.  How do I fix it?

Here some parts of my code about apples.

```
//apples 
game.apples = [];
game.greenApple = true;
game.appleSpeed = 1;
game.count = 2;
game.timeDrop = 1000;

function init() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    game.apples.push({
      x: Math.floor((Math.random() * game.width / 2) + 150),
      y: Math.floor((Math.random() * game.height / 3)),
      size: 30,
      image: 1,
      green: true
    });
  }
  loop();
}

function update() {
  var intervalVar = setInterval(function () {
    getRandApple()
  }, 1000);

  function getRandApple() {
    var randApple = game.apples[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.apples.length)];
    randApple.green = false;    
    return randApple;
  }

  for (i in game.apples[i]) {
    if (!randApple.green) {
      randApple.y += game.appleSpeed;
    }
  }
});
```

The whole JavaScript file can be found here - >>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL2Lpvc0/)<<

Comment: It would be better if you provide a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)(with images) of your entire code. Upload your images to [postimage.org](http://www.postimage.org/) and use those links in your Fiddle.

Comment: The `var randApple` in `getRandApple()` is local to that function and is not the `randApple` in `if(!randApple.green)` that appears a few lines later within `update()`.  I also don't like that for loop in `update()` because `i` doesn't appear in the loop code and the in clause just looks fishy.

Comment: You say it's your first question, but I can't find the actual question.  What is the question?

Comment: @jfriend00 He says the apples fall all at once instead of one at a time.  So it is a bug report with incomplete code dump.

Comment: FYI, you should never iterate an array like this: `for (i in game.apples[i])`.  This iterates all properties of the object, not just array entries.  Use `for (var i = 0; i < game.apples.length; i++)` or `game.apples.forEach()`.

Comment: I added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kL2Lpvc0/ and thanks

Comment: @Paul - I guess it's asking too much for people to put an actual question in a question and perhaps even make it easier to find by ending it with a question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle that makes 5 apples fall one by one at some regular interval,

```
http://jsfiddle.net/h3m5hqzd/6/
```

You could put your logic into hook() function in the fiddle. Here is what I have done,

```
var appleArray = ['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'apple4', 'apple5'];
var appleExistArray = [true, true, true, true, true];
var fallenAppleCount = 0;

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
    while (true) {
        // randomIndex will be within 0 to 4
        var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
        if (appleExistArray[randomIndex] === true) {
            hook(randomIndex);
            appleExistArray[randomIndex] = false;
            if (fallenAppleCount++ === 4) {
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}, 1000);

function hook(randomIndex) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(appleArray[randomIndex] + ' is falling');
    para.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById('msgHolder').appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you! :)